# How can I create individual conversion funnels for 200 companies in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking for a way to setup a funnels to track sign up form conversions for 200 companies that use a single site under a single domain.

Everything is under a single account, single property (UA#), but there are 15 views for each of the categories such as sports, education, or products. Each category is a GA view filtered by the subdirectory: /products, /education, /sports.

However, now they want to look at a per company basis and report on the conversion rate for start and complete sign ups. The problem is that the URL structure jumps out of the category subdirectory and begins with /signup followed by a record database ID (eg. /signup/1234).

Is there a way to use events, virtual page views, category tagging, or some Javascript call to create a funnel for each company?

In the Products GA View (/products), how to report on Nike vs Adidas and 20 others:

Nike: here there are two different shoes that should roll up into Nike

```
/products/nike/landing-22008
/signup/22008/address
/signup/22008/info
/signup/22008/complete

/products/nike/landing-20394
/signup/20394/address
/signup/20394/info
/signup/20394/complete
```

Adidas: here there is just one for comparison.

```
/products/adidas/landing-44112
/signup/44112/address
/signup/44112/info
/signup/44112/complete
```

In the Sports GA View (/sports), how to report on MLB vs NBA and 30 others?

MLB

```
/sports/mlb/landing-93848
/signup/93848/address
/signup/93848/info
/signup/93848/complete

/sports/mlb/landing-94112
/signup/94112/address
/signup/94112/info
/signup/94112/complete
```

NBA

```
/sports/nba/landing-78000
/signup/78000/address
/signup/78000/info
/signup/78000/complete

/sports/nba/landing-78001
/signup/78001/address
/signup/78001/info
/signup/78001/complete

/sports/nba/landing-78002
/signup/78002/address
/signup/78002/info
/signup/78002/complete
```

Each of the IDs is a unique product SKU, job, or event. It is not the ID of the company.

I can't change the URLs, and I can't afford $150,000 for Google 360.

How can I track these funnels within the 15 out of 20 views that I have for each different category and by the 200 companies?

Answer (score 1):

You can create individual tracking IDs for each company and add those to the page. So you can make a new site on analytics named example.comNIKE and add the UA tracker. It won't create any additional bloat to the page as the .js file is already loaded and cached. It'll then show the referral page for each category.

You can also take a look at things like behavior flow. And if you can add these events to behavior you can potentially see them in events flow.

If you click on /sports/nba/landing-78000 or /signup/78000/address in your behavior report and set the secondary dimension to acquisition->referral path or source, you may be able to track and identify which company created the signup conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. We had individual UAs before, but with 200 companies, they didn't want to go that route because it was an Admin nightmare to setup dashboards goals and all the same stuff 200x. In the Behavior, I added a secondary dimension of "previous page," which does show the parent category like I want, but the complete page has no connection to the category, like you'd expect in a true funnel. I have to think there is a way I can add some custom parameter or call to the page view to sort things in the right group.

Answer (score 0):

In Goal Setting, you can use [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to create a generic funnel which applies across all the accounts (as long as there is a pattern).